# Func in method parameter

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to return value from `func<>`?

Like this

```
public interface IMusic
{
    string Type { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<IMusic> Music { get; set; }
}

public class Rap : IMusic
{
    public List<IMusic> Music { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Mix : IMusic
{
    public List<IMusic> Music { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Rock : IMusic
{
    public List<IMusic> Music { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var r = Music<Rock>((a => a.Name));

        Console.WriteLine(r);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static object Music<T>(Func<T, object> music)
    {
        return music;
    }
}
```

For example when i have func in parameter `i` want to return Boolean or String from method

`MethodName(a => a.FirstName == "Test")` = true is it possible ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the method named `Music` ? That's one bad method name by the way. I see no comparison and nothing that might return a boolean, please post a complete example !

Comment: It's for example bro I trying to return func from method

Comment: You're passing a Func to a method that only returns that Func ? This is useless. Anyway, if you need to do that, then you need to change `static object` to `static Func<T, object>`. If you want to execute that Func, you need an object of type `T`. Then you can write `return music(obj);` where `obj` is of type `T`.

Comment: I hope you don't write your programs as sloppily as you write your prose.

Comment: It's just example .. I write it for learn Interfaces ..

Comment: Your example `Program.Main()` does not use any interfaces. Returning an function from a method hasn't anything to do with interfaces. You might rephrase your question and remove all unnecessary code. The answer is, yes, you can return a `Func<>` from a method.

Comment: @Guffy I see no interfaces in the `Program` section. You need to understand that a Func is a method variable. You can pass it around and you can execute it. When you write `Func<T, object>` then this is a method that accepts T as parameter input and returns an object. So you need to execute `music` at some point, to do that you need to pass it an object of type `T` (in your case `Rock`). So you can say: `var rock = new Rock(); return music(rock);` Understand the basics - read more about delegates. That's exactly what you said in your question (*i want to return Boolean or String from method*)